# Quick question about set unions and subsets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Lets say I have three sets: $A, B,$ and $C.$ Every element in sets $A$ and $B$ are contained in set $C$.

So is this statement true? $A \cup B \subset C$

And this is NOT true?: $C \cup A \subset C$

If the second one isn't true, is it because it can't be a proper subset of itself?

Hopefully that makes sense, I've been second guessing myself on this. Sets and subsets aren't my strong suit.

Comment: Are you using the symbol $\subset$ to mean subset or proper subset?  If it means subset, then both statements are true.  If it means proper subset, they are false (in general).

Comment: Honestly, I don't know, sorry. It's apart of a problem for asymptotic notations where A is O(n), B Ω(n), C Θ(n). One is suppose to be true, the other false. Originally the problem was A + B = C and C + A = C but was changed to union and subset notation after the instructor said people weren't reading it correctly.

Comment: Let's say it's a proper subset, would A ∪ C ⊂ B be true? Trying to wrap my head around this, thanks for the help.

Comment: If its a proper subset, it would only sometimes be true. For example, if I have A: {1,2} and B:{3,4}. If C is {1,2,3,4} then A ∪ B would not be a proper subset. However if C is {1,2,3,4,5}, A ∪ B would be a proper subset. It depends on what you set C is and if there are elements in set C that aren't in A or B.

Comment: "If the second one isn't true, is it because it can't be a proper subset of itself?" Yes that is why your second statement would be not true.